# Show revision history link on question for any moderation action (edit, closure, deletion, etc)

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list

### Background

Many events are included in the revisions list, primarily:

- edits
- deletions
- closures

However, the only thing that creates the link to the revisions list is edits. This link is in the form of "edited x minutes ago". This means an  assortments of events can occur to a question that has never been edited without any evidence of that fact.

I tested this on a question of my own which I had never edited, but probably needed a minor edit. You can see the [revision list here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/185591/revisions). I deleted it then undeleted it, all without any revision list link appearing, I finally edited it and the full revisions list was available

### How this affected me

This affected me when I asked a question regarding an on going event. I was criticised for posting a duplicate of a question that was "still on the front page!". However what had actually happened (I eventually found out) was that the original was posted, self deleted and then undeleted a few minutes later (for whatever reason). I posted my duplicate while the original was deleted but there was no (available) record of that until the question was later edited.

### Request

Have any event that are included in the revisions history also generate an appropriate link to the revisions list on the question

Comment: I editted your title slightly.  The way it was written, I had trouble figuring out what you were asking until I got through the question.  Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, it was already title 2. I couldn't find one I liked. Your edit improves it considerably

Answer (score 0):

You can always get to the revision history for a post at /posts/[id]/revisions. E.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/218197/revisions for this question. It might be nice to have a link if there is any activity, but it's not a particularly pressing problem.

Comment: I would say anything that requires URL manipulation doesn't count as a solution. After all unless I knew to look, why would I look? As it happened I was just embarrised